# Plot Table of Equations

Tags: plotting, numerical-integration, mathematical-optimization, list-manipulation

I have a code where the first line of the body consists of an algebraic equation involving `NIntegrate` and the parameter `a`, for a given `a` the solution will be stored as a function `toroot[c_?NumericQ, z_]`, `c` will then be solved as a function of `z` and substituted to the expression `functionS`.

This is all good and I initially placed a value for `a=0.2`, but

(1) What strategy should I employ so that I can write a `functionS` where I can plug in several values for `a` so that in the end I can plot `functionS` vs. `z_s` for different `a`?

(2) I want to find the minimum of `functionS` using `FindMinimum` for different `a`, that is, is there a way to do this in a single code or maybe produce a list of the minimum values. Also, I want to plot the minimum points as a function of `a`.

I believe I will use `Table` but I'm not quite sure how to write the proper efficient code.

```
d = 3;
zh = 1.5;
a = 0.2;
toroot[c_?NumericQ, z_] := a - NIntegrate[(c z^(d + 1) x^d)/((1 - ((z x)/zh)^(d + 1)) (1 - c^2 (z x)^(2 d)))^(1/2), {x, 0, 1}, MaxRecursion -> 5, PrecisionGoal -> 4, Method -> "DuffyCoordinates"]
cz[z_?NumericQ] := c /. FindRoot[toroot[c, z], {c, 0.009, 0.0000001, 100}, WorkingPrecision -> 3]
intS[z_?NumericQ] := NIntegrate[With[{b = z/1.5}, (((-1)/(d - 1)) cz[z]^2 z^(2 d)) x^d ((1 - (b x)^(d + 1))/(1 - cz[z]^2 (z x)^(2 d)))^(1/2) - ((b^(d + 1) (d + 1))/(2 (d - 1))) x ((1 - cz[z]^2 (z x)^(2 d))/(1 - (b x)^(d + 1)))^(1/2) + (b^(d + 1) x)/((1 - (b x)^(d + 1)) (1 - cz[z]^2 (z x)^(2 d)))^(1/2)], {x, 0, 1}, MaxRecursion -> 5, PrecisionGoal -> 4, Method -> "DuffyCoordinates"]
functionS = ((-((1 - cz[z]^2 z^(2 d)) (1 - (z/1.5)^(d + 1)))^(1/2)/(d - 1)) + intS[z] + 1)/(4 z^(d - 1));
function = Log[10, functionS];

Plot[function, {z, 1.3, 1.5}, PlotPoints -> 3, AxesLabel -> {"z_s", "Log S"}, AxesStyle -> Directive[Black, 18], PlotStyle -> {Thick, Blue}, PlotRange -> Full, ImageSize -> Large] // Quiet // AbsoluteTiming

FindMinimum[functionS, {z, 1.46}] // Quiet // AbsoluteTiming
```

[image: Pics]

This plot is only `functionS` for `a=0.2`. What I want to get is a plot of `functionS` say for `a=0.1,0.2,0.3,0.4,0.5`.

UPDATE: Question (1) is already resolved (the reason I cannot do the plots is because I defined `toroot[a_?NumericQ,c_?NumericQ, z_]` instead of `toroot[a_,c_?NumericQ, z_]` as NIntegrate would require a numerical value), BUT (2) is not yet, can anyone help me on this?

Comment: Just define everything as a function of `a`?

Comment: @Natas I have tried that but failed but now I already know why your suggestion did not work, because I need to write `toroot[a_,c_?NumericQ, z_]` instead of `toroot[a_?NumericQ,c_?NumericQ, z_]`. However, my question about `FindMinimum` is still unanswered I want to write a code that gives a minimum of `functionS` for different `a`, also I want to plot the minimum points as a function of `a`.

Comment: To find the minima: `minima = Table[First@FindMinima[functionS[a], {z, 1.3,1.5}], {a, 0.1, 0.5, 0.1}];` To plot them as a function of `a`: `ListPlot[minima, DataRange -> {0.1, 0.5}]`.

Comment: @Natas Your suggestion worked! However, do you know if my code can be made any faster? Since it takes a long time just to plot say, 5 points. I have used `DuffyCoordinates` in `NIntegrate` to avoid any singularities and maybe speed up the calculation. I have also introduced `WorkingPrecision` and `PrecisionGoal`, also I added `MaxRecursion` but I am not quite sure about its real use, any thoughts?

Comment: Unfortunately I have very little experience with numerics in Mathematica. Certainly decreasing the options you mentioned can increase the computation speed. However, of course at a loss of precision. I had a look at the documentation of `"DuffyCoordinates"` and don't think you should use it. Firstly, it's for multidimensional integration and, secondly, you also need to specify `"Corners"` ([relevant documentation](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/NIntegrateIntegrationStrategies.html#66551248)).

Comment: I suggest you have a thorough read of [Introduction to Numerical Integration in the Wolfram Language](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/NIntegrateIntroduction.html).

Comment: @Natas Thanks for your suggestions!